# Странное поведенеи тестов api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Есть api, перед тестированием эндпойнтов происходит JWT аутентификация, по эндпойнту аутентификации.

```
post '/api/v1/authenticate', params: { email: user.email, password: 'password' }
```

Для двух контроллеров все проходит нормально, а для третьего этот запрос почему-то выдает - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0).

Ссылки на тесты:

https://github.com/ValentinAndreev/Blog-with-API/blob/master/spec/api/v1/posts_spec.rb
https://github.com/ValentinAndreev/Blog-with-API/blob/master/spec/api/v1/sessions_spec.rb

Эти работают нормально.

Этот (с совершенно таким же запросом) - нет:

https://github.com/ValentinAndreev/Blog-with-API/blob/master/spec/api/v1/report_spec.rb

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте в него важные части кода. Ссылка на репозиторий - это, конечно, прекрасно, но если он прекратит своё  существование, то вопрос потеряет смысл. Собственно, report_spec уже возвращает 404-ю - это стоит расценивать как то, что вопрос вы решили?

Comment: "Решил" я его переносом тестов в спеку другого api контроллера (posts). Почему отдельно не работало так и не понял.